# SharePoint 2013 online App Setting page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

Im going to start to build a sharepoint app. My app is going to have some hardcoded parameters, can i have a second page beside the startpage, like a settingspage where the users can specify all the parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add as many pages as you want to your app. Depending whether the app that you're building is a SharePoint- or a provider-hosted app you can have the parameters stored either directly in the App Web or in some other repository such as a database.

Comment: Thanks, i will check if there is some guideliness regarding this subject